# Paint a twenty year old door that have some paint peeled off

Tags: doors, paint

If one do not want to use a paint stripper to remove the remaining paint, is it recommend to paint a new water-based wood paint on the door?

[image]

Comment: An answer mentioned **lead paint**. If it is really only 20 years old then you should be OK, but testing may be worthwhile anyway, just in case. If it is much older but "last painted 20 years ago" then lead paint is a real possibility.

Answer (score 1):

First, read up on lead paint.
Second, post a photo.
Third, what's your budget?

Painting water based over oil is possible, but only with good preparation.

Answer (score 0):

If the existing paint is latex there's no problem. If it's oil based it may take a little more prep. For either, a light sanding to knock off any surface shine and loose paint, then a light wash to remove sanding dust, would help the new paint adhere better.

https://www.todayshomeowner.com/video/how-to-paint-over-oil-based-paint-with-latex/

While it would be nice to know if it has lead based paint now, it doesn't change the general prep process. It's only a major concern if you plan to strip the door back to bare wood, which generally isn't necessary.